HTACCESS RewriteCond not working after server change
I recently moved from a common shared cPanel hosting to a dedicated server. Everything works with normal WordPress installations except a custom website performing a targeted HTACCESS rewrite.
Basically takes the domain's third-level and sets it as dedicated parameter, but not on targeted URLs.
This is the code
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.mywebsite\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(css|js|img) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(ajax\.php) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(bridge\.php) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(updates\.php) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^author=
RewriteRule ^ /?author=%1 [L,QSA]

Summarizing: handling https://5.mywebsite.com, must process the URL as https://5.mywebsite.com?author=5
As is, the server returns a blank page with "File not found." error.
Is there anything wrong/missing in the server configuration? Any potential improvement I could do with my HTACCESS code? thanks

What file are you expecting to handle this request? This should be included in the substitution string. You are currently relying on mod_dir (DirectoryIndex) which can vary from server to server (default being index.html unless stated otherwise).

Not targeting any file, just want to manipulate whatever URL used with third-level domain. Taking the third-level name and putting it as URL "author" parameter. Do you mean I should end with RewriteRule ^ index.php/?author=%1 [L,QSA] ? Still doesn't work

But accessing https://5.mywebsite.com/ to begin with, that works?

No, it returns a blank page with "File not found." error (and obviously the fiiles structure is the same I have in the old server)
